# What is the best way to send data from Oracle Siebel to Kafka?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, integration, siebel

I'm trying to integrate Oracle Siebel with Kafka.

What is the best way to send data from Oracle Siebel to Kafka?

Meanwhile I use an open-source Kafka (not confluent or cloudera).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no best way that will suit everyone. If you have strict availability and reliability requirements and willing to pay for software and its support then Oracle GoldenGate is best choise. On the other hand you can try opensource Debezium's Oracle connector. But it's in incubating state as of today so there may be some not yet discovered bugs and major changes in future.